# Find a function that makes this differential form exact

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

We have $\Omega=\mathbb{R^3}\backslash \left\{ (0,0,z):z\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ and $\omega$ the differential form:
$$\omega :=\left(\frac{4x^2+2zx}{x^2+y^2}+2A(x,y)\right)dx+\left(\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}(2x+z)\right)dy+A(x,y)\,dz,$$
where $A\in C^1(\mathbb{R^2}\backslash(0,0); \mathbb{R})$

Find a function $A$ that makes the differential form exact.

My teacher advised to use the homotopy of the curves of which I make the integral. Namely find two curves on which the integral is $0$, one that surrounds the origin and the other doesn't, and hence obtaining all the other curves through continuous deformation. For the curves that don't include the $z$-axis I can just take a ball that contains the curve, and since the ball is convex, I know that a closed differential form in a open convex set is exact (I'm pretty sure it is closed). I'm stuck on the curves that surround the $z$-axis, any ideas?

Comment: Isn't the task just one of solving a differential equation? For the form to be exact you need some $\beta$ such that $\omega = d \beta$. For this to hold you need a function $\beta$ such that $\beta_{,x} = (4x^2+2zx)/(x^2+y^2) + 2 A(x,y)$, $\beta_{,y} = ...$. I think this means we need $A(x,y) = \log(x^2+y^2) + c(x)$ for some differentable function $c$.

Comment: Makes sense, although I've had the impression that my professor wanted us to first proof that the form is exact and then find the primitive, this way looks interesting. How would you find $c$?

Comment: @John: Arthur is telling you how to choose $A$ so that $\omega$ has a primitive. If you have a primitive for $\omega$, then perforce $\omega$ is exact....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first verify that your form is at least closed, that is $d\omega = 0$. If I did everything well, after a lengthy calculation you'll get $A= \log(x^2+y^2)+C$. Finally check that $\int_C \omega = 0$ for some curve sourronding the $z$-axis, I chose the curve $C = (\cos t,\sin t, 0)$ for $0\le t\le 2\pi$, because the integral seems easy to evaluate. Since the interal is zero, your form is exact.

---- Edit -------------

To answer the question of @JBond007, let me write two proofs.

(i) For a closed 1-form $\omega$ we are tempted to define the solution as $f(p)=c+\int_q^p\omega$, for some fixed point $q$. If two curves $C_1$ and $C_2$ join $q$ and $p$, and one of them can be deformed into the other, then they can be seen as the boundary of a surface $S$ and by Stokes theorem $\int_{C_1-C_2}\omega = \int_S d\omega = 0$. The problem here is that $M=\mathbb{R}^3-\{z \enspace\text{axis}\}$ is not simply-connected; however $C_1-C_2$ can be deformed into some loop $C = (\cos t,\sin t, 0)$, for $t\in[0,2\pi n]$, that turns $n$ times around the $z$ axis (smash $C_1-C_2$ into the plane $\{z=0\}$ and then contract to $S^1$), so by Stokes Theorem again $\int_{C_1-C_2}\omega=\int_C\omega$. Hence, if the integral around $C$ is zero, then there is no obstruction to define $f(p)=c+\int_q^p\omega$, since the definition does not depend on the curve joining $p$ and $q$.

(ii) You can use an exact sequence. Write $M=U_1\cup U_2$, where $U_1:=\mathbb{R}^3-\{x\ge 0 \text{ and } y=0\}$ and $U_2:=\mathbb{R}^3-\{x\le 0 \text{ and } y=0\}$. Both $U_1$ and $U_2$ are simply-connected, so you can find a solution $\omega = df_i$ in $U_i$. In $U_1\cap U_2$ we have that $0=df_1-df_2$, which implies that $f_1-f_2$ is constant in each connected component of $U_1\cap U_2 = \{y>0\}\cup\{y<0\}$, say $c_+$ in $\{y>0\}$ and $c_-$ in $\{y<0\}$. If $c_+=c_-=c$ then the solution $f = f_1$ in $U_1$ and $f = f_2+c$ in $U_2$ is well defined in $M$. The integral of $\omega=df_1$ on the half-loop $C_1=\{(\cos t,\sin t, 0)\mid t\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2]\}\subset U_1$ is $f_1(0,1,0)-f_1(0,-1,0)$, and the integral on the other half-loop inside $U_2$ is $f_2(0,-1,0)-f_2(0,1,0)$. Hence, if $\int_C\omega = 0$ then $0=(f_1(0,1,0)-f_2(0,1,0))-(f_1(0,-1,0)-f_2(0,-1,0))=c_+-c_-$, and $c_+=c_-$.

Comment: Why the fact that $\int_C\omega=0$ assure me that $\omega$ is exact?